# adding node to tikz figure

Tags: macros, nodes, tikz-pic, neuralnetwork

I want to add text where I put the dots, for example `w_1, w_2, ... w_n`.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
   neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=2,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\newcommand{\DrawNeuronalNetwork}[2][]{
\xdef\Xmax{0}
\foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{max(\X,\Xmax)}
 \xdef\Xmax{\Xmax}
 \xdef\Ymax{\Y}
}
\foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\node[anchor=south] at ({2*\Y},{\Xmax/2+0.1}) {\Layer};
 \foreach \m in {1,...,\X}
 {
  \ifnum\m=\Miss
   \node [neuron missing] (neuron-\Y-\m) at ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {};
  \else
   \node [circle, draw=black, thick, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1cm] (neuron-\Y-\m) at 
  ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {};
 \ifnum\Y=1
  \else
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\LastY}{\Y-1}
   \foreach \Z in {1,...,\LastX}
   {
    \ifnum\Z=\LastMiss
    \else
     \draw[->] (neuron-\LastY-\Z) -- (neuron-\Y-\m);
    \fi
    }
  \fi
 \fi
 \ifnum\Y=1
  \ifnum\m=\X
   \draw [<-] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- ++(-1,0) node [above, midway] {$\Lab_{\Count}$};
  \else
   \ifnum\m=\Miss
   \else
    \draw [<-] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- ++(-1,0) node [above, midway] {$\Lab_{\m}$};
   \fi
  \fi
 \else
   \ifnum\Y=\Ymax
    \ifnum\m=\X
     \draw [->] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- ++(1,0) node [above, midway] {$\Lab_{\Count}$};
    \else
     \ifnum\m=\Miss
     \else
      \draw [->] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- ++(1,0) node [above, midway] {$\Lab_{\m}$};
     \fi
    \fi
   \else
     \ifnum\m=1
      \node[above=0pt of neuron-\Y-\m] {$\Lab_1$};
     \fi
     \ifnum\m=\X
      \node[below=0pt of neuron-\Y-\m] {$\Lab_{\Count}$};
     \fi
   \fi
 \fi     
 }
 \xdef\LastMiss{\Miss}
 \xdef\LastX{\X}
}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth,font=\sffamily]
\DrawNeuronalNetwork{
Capa de entrada/1/black/8/x/,
Capa oculta/7/black/6/H/k,
%Bottleneck Layer/3/blue/2/T/f,
%Demapping Layer/7/red/4/G/f,
Capa de salida/1/black/4/y(x)/}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot happening in your code. Maybe a more TikZ-automatic way to place the nodes could help you.

Here I'm using the [`chains` library](https://tikz.dev/library-chains) to place nodes automatically:

- Chain `main` has always only three nodes.
- From the middle of these three (see `start branch 2` style) two branches are started:

  - `main/up` and
  - `main/down`.

On `main/up` we will place `up nodes` − 1 additional nodes, on `main/down` the same for `down nodes`.

For the `down` branch we define a style `down <down nodes - 1>` style that sets the `\vdots` in relation to the total number of `down nodes` so that it is always the second to last node.

Similar calculations are done in the very last `\foreach` loop where we want to skip the `\vdots` node when drawing the arrows.

You can of course – similar on how I added the arrows with `x` and `y(x)` – just draw these arrows manually.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes, chains, scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x = 2.5cm, y = 1.5cm,
  node distance = .5cm and 2.5cm,
  %
  vertex/.style={
    shape = circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=1cm,
    node contents=},
  start branch 2/.style={
    insert path={
      {[start branch = up going above]}
      {[start branch = down going below]}}},
  %
  > = {Stealth [sep=2pt 1]},
  start chain = main going right,
  up nodes/.initial = 4,
  down nodes/.initial = 4,
  declare function={
      upnum(\x) = int(-\x + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/up\space nodes}+1);
    downnum(\x) = \x == \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/down\space nodes} ? "k"
            : int( \x + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/up\space nodes}-1);
  }
]
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}
  \node[on chain, vertex] [start branch \i/.try];

\path (main-1) edge[<-, "$x$" above]   ++ (left:1)
      (main-3) edge[->, "$y(x)$"above] ++ (right:1);

{ [continue branch=up]
  \foreach \i in {2,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/up nodes}}
    \node[on chain, vertex]; }
{ [continue branch=down,
   % second to last:
   down \the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/down nodes}-1\relax/.style
     = {node contents = $\vdots$, draw = none}]
  \foreach \i in {2,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/down nodes}}
    \node[on chain, vertex, down \i/.try]; }

\path (main/up-end)   [late options = {label = above:$H_1$}]
      (main/down-end) [late options = {label = below:$H_k$}];

{ [nodes={node font=\scriptsize, sloped}]
\foreach \t[
  evaluate={\n=upnum \t;}
] in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/up nodes}}
  \path[->] (main-1)     edge["$ w _{\n} $"] (main/up-\t)
            (main/up-\t) edge["$ w'_{\n} $"]  (main-3);

\foreach \t[
  expand list,
  evaluate={\n=downnum \t;}
] in {2, ..., % third to last, skip second to last, last
  \the\numexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/down nodes}-2\relax,
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/down nodes}}
  \path[->] (main-1)       edge["$ w _{\n} $"] (main/down-\t)
            (main/down-\t) edge["$ w'_{\n} $"]  (main-3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]